# How can I safely keep the value of a password field during postbacks in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

is there a way to safely keep the value of a password field during postbacks in ASP.NET?
I was thinking of the viewstate, but I don't want to print it clearly in the HTML code by setting the control value equals to the viewstate content at every postback.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need to do this?

Comment: Specific requirement by the customer on a pre-existing web app...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If security is a concern, you should either :

- Use HTTPS
- At the bare minimum never store plain password even in your database but say a MD5 hash of the password(bare minimum).
  -Use this hash instead of the password in your postbacks

Answer (score 1):

You should not save the value of the password in the viewstate, since the view state is visible to the end user.
You can save it in a session object if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of how well this would pan out in an ASP.NET application but take a look into [System.Security.SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx).

This will allow you to populate a string which is encrypted using machine specific (your server) encryption. You will need to marshal this object to a usable (and decrypted) string when it is required, which, I believe, is why some are divided as to its usefulness - I think there are ways and whens to use it, and not.